# Regex first portion starts with number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-lookarounds

Why does my JavaScript regular expression not work?

```
var regexp = /^[1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/;
console.log(regexp.test('sfdf sfdf'));
```

The rule is simple: the string must start with any number (0-9) followed by any number(s) and/or letter(s) and must allow whitespace. Some valid examples:

- 202Ab second text and maybe more
- 333333 second text and maybe more
- 202aaa second text and maybe more
- 23B second text and maybe more

Invalid example:

- a202 second text and maybe more
- Second text and maybe more

Comment: So basically any number followed by anything? `/^\d.+/`

Comment: You anchor the match to the start of the string (good); but then you say "anything in the set 1-9, a-z, or A-Z".  Shouldn't it just be /^[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z \t]*$/ ?

Comment: Special characters must not be allowed, like comma, asterisk, slashes, etc. Just numbers, letters and white spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex reads:

- any letter or digits 1-9
- any number of (letter, number or space)

This is hardly what you said:

- any digit
- any number of (letter, number or space)

  ```
  var regexp = /^\d[0-9a-z ]*$/i;
  ```